# NSDateComponents weekOfYear returns wrong date

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

so i am making a basic week picker, where you can pick a week number and year, and get the corresponding date from the weeks startpoint.

A basic test scenario

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.year = 2015
components.weekOfYear = 15
print(calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!)
```

You can see, that i set the wanted year to 2015 and the wanted week to 15, but the result i get is:  "2014-12-31 23:00:00 +0000"

... and thats really gets me hanging. No matter what week and year i choose, it will always be off and in december.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`weekOfYear` works in conjunction with `yearForWeekOfYear`:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = NSDateComponents()

components.yearForWeekOfYear = 2015
components.weekOfYear = 15

print(calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!)
// 2015-04-05 22:00:00 +0000
```

---

Update for **Swift 3** and later:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var components = DateComponents()

components.yearForWeekOfYear = 2015
components.weekOfYear = 15

print(calendar.date(from: components)!)
```

Comment: little interesting note,  setting the weekday to 1 also yields the result,  just thought it was interesting and should be mentioned

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: Interesting, that seems to work as well. But you better set `components.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday`, because Sunday is not the first day in the week everywhere.