# Get last monday from calendar Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

I need to get date of last monday from today , but the below code fails .. i.e if try  Jan 5 2018 , i can not get Jan 1 2018.. Can you tell me what the mistake ? Thanks in advance.

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponent;
dateComponent = [calendar components:(NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // Jan 5 2018


NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
components.weekday = 2;
components.weekOfYear = dateComponent.weekOfYear;
components.year = dateComponent.year;
NSDate *dateStart = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents: components];
NSLog(@"last monday is : %@", dateStart) //last monday is : 2018-12-31
```

Comment: If the current day is monday what should return your algoritm?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Obviously not current monday, i mean last one it should return.

Comment: You have to set `components.yearForWeekOfYear`, as pointed out in the "duplicate".

Comment: @MartinR I think is not a really duplicated from the question marked as duplicate, correct me if I am wrong please

Comment: @ReinierMelian: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33767450/1187415 explains why OP's code fails to work as expected. But I have reopened it because better solutions are possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated method `nextDateAfterDate:matchingUnit:value:options:` of `NSCalendar` which provides exactly what you want.

Just pass `NSCalendarUnitWeekday` with `value` 2 and search ***backwards***.

```
NSDate *dateStart = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] nextDateAfterDate:[NSDate date] 
                                                       matchingUnit: NSCalendarUnitWeekday 
                                                              value: 2
                                                            options:NSCalendarSearchBackwards | NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
NSLog(@"last monday is : %@", dateStart); //last monday is : 2018-01-01
```

Comment: Perhaps close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/40155764/1187415 ?

Comment: Yes, I closed it. The duplicate reminded me of the still more convenient API.